# how to build a new docker image and start container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, logstash, dockerfile

I am new to Docker. I want to push rabbitmq messages to elastic.

Now I have two logstash-indexer images: `ctdcto23:5000/logstash-indexer:latest` and `ctdcto23:5000/logstash-indexer:1.0.0-rc3`. The differece between them is `indexer.conf`. The former is

```
    input { 
        redis {
            host => ''
            port => 
            key => ''
            password => ''
            data_type => 'list'
            tags => ['service-log']
        }
        rabbitmq {
            host => ''
            user => ''
            password => ''
            port => 5672
            queue => 'security audit'
            exchage => 'exchange'
            key => 'security audit'
            durable => 'true'
        }
    }
```

while the latter omits rabbitmq. The yaml file is as following:

```
    redis:
      image: ctdcto23:5000/redis:1.0.0-rc1
      restart: always
      ports:
       - "6379:6379"

    elasticsearch:
      image: ctdcto23:5000/elasticsearch:1.0.0-rc3
      restart: always
      ports:
       - "9200:9200"
       - "9300:9300"
      volumes:
       - /var/local/esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      command: elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name="xx-cluster" -Des.node.name="xx-1"

    kibana:
      image: ctdcto23:5000/kibana:4.0.3
      restart: always
      links:
       - elasticsearch
      ports:
       - "5601:5601"

    logstash-indexer:
      image: ctdcto23:5000/logstash-indexer:1.0.0-rc3
      restart: always
      links:
       - redis
       - elasticsearch
      environment:
       - OPTS=--verbose
```

Build image with Dockfile:

```
    FROM ctdcto23:5000/logstash:latest
    MAINTAINER xxx

    # Add a directory to process setup scripts for the container
    RUN mkdir -p /opt/logstash/conf /opt/logstash/patterns

    COPY indexer.conf /opt/logstash/conf/
    COPY patterns/* /opt/logstash/patterns/
    COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
    RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

    ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    CMD ["logstash"]
```

The issue is that when I build new image and start it with yaml file. The container status is always restarting and could not get into container.

Comment: The yaml file you posted is supposed to be run with `docker-compose`. I don't get the execution path you are doing; can you write how are you running (and building) the containers? Anyway you can use `docker exec` to run an interactive session ("enter the container") from inside containers already running.

Comment: @Javier I start container with docker-compose command. When I use docker run to build with images directly,  I could get into container with 1.0.0-rc3 and fail with latest . The fact is that I with build image with the Dockfile and start container with yaml file. Different Logstash input  are in indexer.conf file.